# PHP | Unset array inside array if that value exist in other array

Tags: php, arrays

i have two arrays.

**Array 1 :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 2
        )

)
```

**Array 2:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 2
        )

)
```

what i want is if in `Array 1` values exists which in Array 2 exists then unset those arrays from `Array 1`

in the above example from array 1 the array with `employee_id = 2` should be unset. as it exists in Array 2

and Result i would get like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: my question is how to unset the values from array 1 if it exist in array 2

Comment: Ah ok, good. So my vote to close as "too broad" was accurate then. You need to provide details about specifically where your stuck (edit them into the question). "write this code for me" is not a popular request around here

Comment: @Clive
Too Broad?? all i want is to unset the array from Array 1 which already exist or same as array in Array2, if it do not matches with Array 2 then dont unset.. i think that is not too broad question..

Comment: What's about [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-diff.php) or [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-intersect.php)?

Comment: @pbaldauf
I have tried array_diff for which i got error.. array to string convertion thats why i am asking this quesiton. as both of them are multidimentional arrays.

Comment: Best of luck getting an answer then. You may want to pay attention to what people are telling you in comments, we're not doing it for our sake. Just a friendly thought.

Comment: you should be using [array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

Comment: @bansi
Thanks. Problem Solved with cxminer answer, but i also tried your solution too but with using array_diff_assoc() i got this error
`Array to string conversion`

Comment: i got 2 vote downs.. my even thou solution is posted for a genuine question. so i guess i will delete the question. if it bothers others..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: ($arr1 keeps ONLY what is NOT inside $arr2)

```
$arr1 = array(
    array(
        'employee_id' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'employee_id' => 2
    )
);

$arr2 = array(
    array(
        'employee_id' => 2
    )
);

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr2); $i++) {
    $employee_id = $arr2[$i]['employee_id'];

    for($j = 0; $j < count($arr1); $j++) {
        if($arr1[$j]['employee_id'] == $employee_id) {
            unset($arr1[$j]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($arr1); // outputs: array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["employee_id"]=> int(1) } }
```

Comment: No, i want array1 to keep those what is not inside array2.

Comment: @Sizzling Fixed it, check now.

Comment: Many Thanks.. Its Perfect, Thats what i wanted. and here @clive said i asked a broad question and voted for closed. :(

But Many many thanks.. You saved alot of my time.. i tried `array_diff` but that didn't worked out for me.

Comment: You did, it has 3/5 required close votes and should be gone soon, so the system is coping (slowly, unfortunately). It's also unfortunate that some people choose to enable this behaviour by spoon-feeding lazy developers, but that's what you get with gamification. Make some effort in future, don't just expect people to do your work for you, and you'll find it doesn't happen again. Continue abusing the system and it'll keep on happening. Your call :)

Comment: @Clive I thought the point of stackoverflow was to help people solve their problems. Just because they have trouble describing the problem doesn't mean it should be down voted...

Comment: No @cxminer, that's a common mistake. The point of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers that are applicable to a wide audience. This sort of question, the "I want this, what's the code?" type, are low quality support requests which we try very hard to avoid keeping around. Answering this type of question by simply providing the OP a code dump is useless, detrimental even, to the goal of the site.

Comment: @Clive I see, I appreciate the explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With this solution you get all the values which are stored in `$arr1` as well as in `$arr2`, but also if they are only in `$arr1`.

```
$arr1 = array( 
           array('employee_id' => 1), 
           array('employee_id' => 3), 
           array('employee_id' => 2),
        );
$arr2 = array(
           array('employee_id' => 1),
           array('employee_id' => 2),
           array('employee_id' => 4),
        );  

$arr1 = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);

print_r($arr1);
```

**Outputs**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: this is better so removing mine